# Leaflet marker addEventListener

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I check if a marker using [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) was clicked?I want to trigger a function if `marker.addEventListener("click")` is true. What is the correct way to do it?

This is my function:

```
function myFunction(title) {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'try/',
        type: 'post',
        data: {phone:title,  csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken}, //this will get the method that will check if the numbr is there
        success: function(data) {
            alert(title);
        },
        failure: function(data) { 
            alert('Got an error dude');
        }
    }); 
}
```

I want to call the above function if the following case is true:

```
if(marker.onclick == true){
     myFunction(title)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `marker. addEventListener('click', _markerOnClick);`

```
var _markerOnClick = function(e) {
 .....(write your code here);
};
```

If your are using the `JQuery` write `marker.on('click', _markerOnClick);`

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question. This solution works but because I have multiple markers on the same map it keeps printing the alert message for all of them. The reason being I am running a for loop for all the markers. Is there are a way to assign to a className for markers?

Comment: You mean change the icon when you click the marker.

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me:

get an array of markers from db then iterate and add to each marker a listener:

```
var mapMarkers = [];
var allMarkers = [];
function loadmarkers(){
        downloadUrl("/functions/rpc/maps/loadmarkers.php", function (data) {
            allMarkers = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var key in allMarkers){
                var point1 = parseFloat(allMarkers[key].lat);
                var point2 = parseFloat(allMarkers[key].lng);

                mapMarkers.push(L.marker([point1, point2]).addTo(mymap).addEventListener('click', _markerOnClick));

            }
        });
    }

    var _markerOnClick = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
```